# .htaccess file - AllowOveride not supported by webhotel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I got a problem because im trying to do some URL Rewriting using my .htaccess file. Im new to using the .htaccess file so i dont know if the answer to this is obvious but i asked around yesterday and i was told that i needed to set the Allowoveride to ALL for my .htaccess file to work.

The problem is that my webhotel does not support the user to access the root folder (lower then domain root (/domain.com/ HERE ))

Is there a way around the .htaccess file to convert the URL to friendly?

My code is as following (domain changed for example).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.dk$ [NC]

ErrorDocument 400 /?fejl=400

ErrorDocument 401 /?fejl=401

ErrorDocument 403 /?fejl=403

ErrorDocument 404 /?fejl=404

ErrorDocument 500 /?fejl=500

RewriteRule fag/(.*)/aflevering/(.*)/ index.php?fag=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule fag/(.*)/ index.php?fag=$1
RewriteRule aflevering/(.*)/ index.php?id=$2
```

Comment: You need to set AllowOverride in the apache config, if you don't have access, ask your host to do it to allow .htaccess use. If they won't find a new host.

Comment: okay thank you. They wont so im changing the host now. so bad service... (the host)